# What is the mean and standard deviation of ImageNet?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, imagenet

Is there a credible link which points out to the mean and standard deviation of ImageNet data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to find a more credible link than the pytorch implementation of AlexNet on ImageNet:

https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/97304e232807082c2e7b54c597615dc0ad8f6173/imagenet/main.py#L197-L198

and the explanation of how they got those numbers:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/normalization-in-the-mnist-example/457/7